# Colored balls detectable by EV3 color sensor

Tags: ev3, piece-information, colour, balls

I'm looking for large balls in standard Lego colors that are detectable by the EV3 color scanner.

So black, white, green, brown, yellow and blue and between 5 and 10 cm.

I'm aware of the [Duplo balls](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41250#T=C):

[image: 45016 set image]

But they do not seem to exist for all the 7 colors.

Are there any other larger balls from Lego in the standard colors?

Is there any third party offering them?

How much can the colors differ from the Lego colors so that they are still detectable by the EV3 color scanner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an interesting discussion on this on the [lejos.sourceforge.io forum](https://lejos.sourceforge.io/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7412).

> the calibration values for the NXT sensor are set in the factory and seem to be different for each sensor (which implies that there must be a reasonable amount of variation between different sensors). On the NXT the RGB values are true raw values and the calibration adjustments used to identify Lego colors are made in the leJOS driver.

But on the EV3 there is no calibration, and the sensor RGB mode

> is not well documented and was not exposed at all in the first version of the Lego software...So the bottom line is I doubt if anyone outside of Lego (and maybe NI) knows if the RGB values are raw sensor readings or if any sort of calibration data has been applied

So it doesn't sound like you will have a consistent set of data anyway - I'd suggest just seeing what coloured balls you can get cheaply and just trying them.